# PlayFramework obj to json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

From: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonHttp

Playframework Scala way:

```
    case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

    case class Place(name: String, location: Location)

    object Place {

      var list: List[Place] = {
        List(
          Place(
            "Sandleford",
            Location(51.377797, -1.318965)
          ),
          Place(
            "Watership Down",
            Location(51.235685, -1.309197)
          )
        )
      }

    }

    implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
      (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
    )(unlift(Location.unapply))

    implicit val placeWrites: Writes[Place] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "location").write[Location]
    )(unlift(Place.unapply))
    Next we write our Action:

    def listPlaces = Action {
      val json = Json.toJson(Place.list)
      Ok(json)
    }
```

Is there is simpler way to do it? Without all this obvious implicits ? I just want it convert all object structure as it is. Like on JS when work with JSON.

Assuming i'm O.K. with default field names and default object structure. Can I I make use of "default advantage-sugar" ?.

**UPDATE:**

As simple as in `NodeJS` for example:

```
var list = {"places":[
    {"name":"Sandleford", "location":{"lat": "1", "long": "222"}}, 
    {"name":"Watership Down", "location":{"lat": "2", "long": "333"}},
]}

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json(list);   
});
```

There is no question what should be localized and how.

Or like in `java` (pure `jackson`):

```
List list = Arrays.asList(place1, place2);
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(list);
```

Where class Place defined with no annotation (but with getters and setters, what I don't like though).

I may use `jackson` in `scala`, but I wonder about 'official defaults'.. in `playframewok` for scala to go with less code (like it is supposed to be).

Comment: Do you still want to deserialize to `Location` and `Place` , or ?

Comment: I want to serialize Place that have Location in it. I've put my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Json.writes[T]`

If all you want is literal serialization to Json, and you don't want to write the `Writes` instances yourself you can use the `Json.writes[T]` macro to generate the `Writes[T]` for you.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

case class Place(name: String, location: Location)

object Place {

  val list: List[Place] = {
    List(
      Place(
        "Sandleford",
        Location(51.377797, -1.318965)
      ),
      Place(
        "Watership Down",
        Location(51.235685, -1.309197)
      )
    )
  }

}

object JsonStuff {
  implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = Json.writes[Location]

  implicit val placeWrites: Writes[Place] = Json.writes[Place]
}
```

Then on the repl,

```
scala> import JsonStuff._
import JsonStuff._

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> Json.toJson(Place.list)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"name":"Sandleford","location":{"lat":51.377797,"long":-1.318965}},{"name":"Watership Down","location":{"lat":51.235685,"long":-1.309197}}]
```

## Json Literals

If you *really* want to you can of course just create and manipulate the `JsValue` directly. For instance

```
object Place {
  val JsList =
    JsArray(
      Seq(
        Json.obj(
          ("name" -> "Sandleford"),
          ("location" ->
            Json.obj(
              ("lat" -> 51.377797),
              ("long" -> -1.318965)))),
        Json.obj(
          ("name" -> "Watership Down"),
          ("location" ->
            Json.obj(
              ("lat" -> 51.235685),
              ("long" -> -1.309197))))))

}
```

On the repl,

```
scala> Place.JsList
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [{"name":"Sandleford","location":{"lat":51.377797,"long":-1.318965}},{"name":"Watership Down","location":{"lat":51.235685,"long":-1.309197}}]
```

Though this approach can be quite difficult to work with for all but the most trivial applications and I would *highly* recommend against it.

Comment: I tried this also, for **writers**, when put it into OK action:
**Ok(Json.toJson(Place.list))** I get error: **No unapply function found** for this line: *implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = Json.writes[Location]*  (I use Scala version 2.11.4 and latest Play)

Comment: Hm.. I had to move my case classes out of the Controller and Get rid of object Place. Then it works with writers.

Answer (score 0):

As **isomarcte** already answered. I had to do this (and this almost satisfied me as noise-free solution):

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)
case class Place(name: String, location: Location)

// little noise (just too lines, but that could be even one @Json. Could..     
object JsonStuff {
 implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = Json.writes[Location]
 implicit val placeWrites: Writes[Place] = Json.writes[Place]
}

object Application extends Controller {

 def places = Action {

    import play.api.libs.json._

      val list: List[Place] = {
        List(
          Place(
            "Sandleford",
            Location(51.377797, -1.318965)
          ),
          Place(
            "Watership Down",
            Location(51.235685, -1.309197)
          )
        )
      }


    import JsonStuff._

    Ok(Json.toJson(list))

}
```

And I had to:

1. to move case classes out - to make them stand alone
2. delete `Place` object to make `list` stands by itself

otherwise I had: **No unapply function found** error.
([known limitations](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception))

3. and sequence of putting  `implicit val ..writers` does matter - `Place` should know about `Location` .. since those writers are macros.. Like in JS :) heh.

otherwise you will get `NullPotinter` exception

(a little bit overcomplicated as for me)